# How do I search an array of objects in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have logs coming into Kibana with this format:

```
{
  "starttime": "2019-04-07T23:31:07.855Z",
  "maxlevel": "ERROR",
  "messages": [
    {
      "time": "2019-04-07T23:31:07.861Z",
      "level": "ERROR",
      "message": "[application.controllers.RestApiController] no_staff_member Please identify yourself"
    },
    {
      "time": "2019-04-07T23:31:07.862Z",
      "level": "INFO",
      "message": "[application.controllers.RestApiController] received request"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I write a query in Kibana to search for any log entries where messages.message does contain "no_staff_member"?

I have tried:

1. `messages.message:no_staff_member`
2. `messages.message:/.*no_staff_member.*/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to query direct in the `messages` field, it will perform a full text query on the field, you can't query inside the fields on the array.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html):

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype instead of the object datatype.

You can change it if you map your field as a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) or if you denormalize your data before index on elasticsearch.